# Gulp cheerio is partially escaping html elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, cheerio, gulp-cheerio

Created a separate minimal example repository illustrating what is happening here (See README.md for instructions on how to run):

https://github.com/oleersoy/nunjucks-cheerio/

The file being rendered is `src/test.html`.  It contains:

```
{% for item in ['100', '300'] %}
  <div class="u-color-background-gray-{{item}}>
    <code>u-color-background-gray-{{item}}</code>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When rendered some content is escaped, even though `gulp-cheerio` operation is supposed to be a noop, because the content it should act on does not exist:

```
  <div class="u-color-background-gray-100&gt;
    &lt;code&gt;u-color-background-gray-100&lt;/code&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;

  &lt;div class=" u-color-background-gray-300="">
    <code>u-color-background-gray-300</code>
  </div>
```

The `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
    gulp.task('test', function() {
      return gulp
        .src("src/**")
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
          path: ["src"]
        }))
        .pipe(cheerio(function($, file) {
          $('.Test-markup > code').each(function() {
            var markup = $(this).html();
            //Insert the Test-render block after the Test-then block
            //Append the markup block to the Test-render block
            $($(this).parent().next()).after(renderTestBlock).next().append(markup);
          });
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
    });
```

Anyone know what might be causing the content to escape?

As a reference I also filed issues with [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/972) and [gulp-cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/972)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing a `"` in the template string `class="u-color-background-gray-{{item}}>`